# Powershell returns Local copy not supported while using variables in pscp

Tags: powershell, ssh, sftp, winscp, pscp

I am struggling for a while with using variable with pscp command.

```
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
.\pscp.exe -pw $password create_ssh $myUsername@$Server:/home/$myUsername/create_ssh
.\plink.exe -pw $password $myUsername@$Server -C "uname -r"
}
```

Output

```
Local to local copy not supported
2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64
```

When I try to specify hostname not using variable there isnt any issue with transferring of the file.
However If I try to use variable $Server, I get an error "Local copy not supported"
I thought it might be problem with variable itself but .\plink works without any issues

I have tried to use commas, escape @, full paths etc. nothing seems to be working.
I cant use winscp.dll since in this specific case I need automatically accept host keys (which is insecure but really specific only to this case) - this is only provided by pscp.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: WinSCP .NET assembly does support automatic accepting of host keys (use [`SessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#giveupsecurityandacceptanysshhostkey)), exactly contrary to pscp, which does not.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I stumbled across this issue as well.  It turns out that you need to use the subexpression operator `$()` for the server variable like so:

```
$($Server)
```

So your commands would look like this:

```
.\pscp.exe -pw $password create_ssh $myUsername@$($Server):/home/$myUsername/create_ssh
.\plink.exe -pw $password $myUsername@$($Server) -C "uname -r"
```